# The Laplacian of the squared length of a (0,2)-tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensor-products, laplacian

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection. Suppose $T$ is a smooth $(0,2)$-tensor field on $M$, and it is given by $$T=T_{ij}dx_i\otimes dx_j$$ in local coordinates, where we adopt the summation convention on repeated indices.

The squared length of $T$ is given by
$$|T|^2=\langle T,T\rangle=T_{ij}T_{kl}\langle dx_i,dx_k\rangle\langle dx_j,dx_l\rangle=T_{ij}T_{kl}g^{ik}g^{jl},$$
where $(g^{ij})$ is the inverse of $(g_{ij}).$

Let $\Delta_M$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $M.$ I am now puzzled at the calculation of $\Delta_M|T|^2.$

In the spirit of Page 134, Line 17 of Han's Book [Nonlinear Elliptic Equations of the Second Order](http://www.ams.org/books/gsm/171/), we should have $$\frac{1}{2}\Delta_M|T|^2=\frac{1}{2}\Delta_M(g^{ik}g^{jl}T_{ij}T_{kl})=g^{ik}g^{jl}T_{kl}\Delta_MT_{ij}+g^{ik}g^{jl}g^{pq}T_{kl;p}T_{ij;q},$$ where we use the notation that $$T_{ij;k}:=\nabla_{\partial_k}T(\partial_i,\partial_j).$$
At this stage, I can understand the appearance of the term $g^{ik}g^{jl}T_{kl}\Delta_MT_{ij}.$ Probably by using $g^{ij}_{;k}=0,$ those terms with $T_{kl}T_{ij}$ may disappear. However, I do not know why do the covariant coefficients $T_{kl;p}$ and $T_{ij;q}$ appear, and I think it should be directional derivatives $T_{kl,p}$ and $T_{ij,q}.$

Comment: Why is it the directional derivative though? Do you know what is $\Delta_M T$?

Comment: For example, we consider the Hessian of the product of two functions $u$ and $v$. We have $\nabla^2(uv)=u\nabla^2v+du\otimes dv+dv\otimes du+v\nabla^2 u,$ then only directional derivatives involves in the term $du(\partial_i)dv(\partial_j)+dv(\partial_j)du(\partial_j)=u_{,i}v_{,j}+u_{,j}v_{,i}.$ By the way, $\Delta_MT$ can be viewed as the trace of $\nabla^2T.$

Comment: Well, in the case of functions, direction derivatives and covariant derivative are the same.

Comment: If we start with the calculation of $\nabla^2|T|^2,$ then the directional derivatives of $g^{ij}$ will also appear in several mixed terms. This also puzzles me.

Comment: Yeah. However in my problem, $T_{kl;p}$ is the coefficients of the covariant derivative $\nabla T.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can write $|T|^2 = \mathrm{L}( g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1} \otimes T\otimes T)$ where $\mathrm{L}$ is taking traces of some indices. By defintion, for any tensor $G$,

$$ \Delta G = \mathrm{tr} \nabla ^2 G.$$

So to calculate $\Delta |T|^2$, we first calculate $\nabla ^2 |T|^2$. Since $\nabla g^{-1} = 0$ and that $\nabla $ commutes with $\mathrm{L}$,

$$ \nabla |T|^2 = L(g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}\otimes \nabla T \otimes T) + L(g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}\otimes T \otimes \nabla T)$$
and
$$\nabla ^2|T|^2 = L(g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}\otimes \nabla^2 T \otimes T) + 2L(g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}\otimes \nabla T \otimes \nabla T) + L(g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}\otimes T \otimes \nabla^2 T)$$

This implies

\begin{align} 
\Delta |T|^2 &= \mathrm{tr} \nabla ^2 |T|^2 \\
&=L(g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}\otimes \Delta T \otimes T) + 2 \mathrm{tr} L(g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}\otimes \nabla T \otimes \nabla T) + L(g^{-1} \otimes g^{-1}\otimes T \otimes \Delta T).
\end{align}

The first and third terms give $2g^{ij} g^{kl} T_{ik} (\Delta T)_{jl}$ and the second term gives $2g^{mn} g^{ij} g^{kl} \nabla_m T_{ik} \nabla _n T_{jl}$.

Comment: In the third display, you forgot to add the superscript 2 to the nabla: it should read as $\nabla ^2 |T|^2 = \dots$